# Unexpected end of line seen In makefile

Tags: makefile

```
all: operation

operation: operation.o operation_functions.o
    $(gcc) $(-std=c99 -Wall) -o operation operation.o operation_functions.o

operation.o: operation.c operation_functions.h
    $(gcc) $(-std=c99 -Wall) -c operation.c

operation_functions.o: operation_functions.c operation_functions.h
    $(gcc) $(-std=c99 -Wall) -c operation_functions.c

test: operation
    operation 7 5 10 15
    operation 0.57 0.9 3.5 9.12
    operation 0 -9 0 -3
    operation 0.467 13 0 -4
    operation 0 8 9 15
    operation 0 0 15 30
    operation 12 0 0 0

clean:
    rm -f *.o operation
```

this is the makefile im using and when run it says unexpected end of line seen in line 3 im not sure whats going on and would love an explanation.

Comment: Check all the indentation is real tabs, not whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

First, check all the indentation are real tabs, not spaces. Make must use real tabs for silly historical reasons.

Next, `$(-std=c99 -Wall)` is a problem. [`$(foo)` is used to refer to the contents of a variable called `foo`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html). Since there's no variable called `-std=c99 -Wall`, `$(-std=c99 -Wall)` will produce nothing.

Similarly `$(gcc)` is probably also a problem. Unless you've defined a `gcc` environment variable it will be empty. You probably just want plan `gcc`. Actually you probably want `$(CC)` which is a cross-platform way to pick an appropriate C compiler.

```
$(CC) -std=c99 -Wall -o operation operation.o operation_functions.o
```

---

An appropriate use of functions would be to place all your C compiler flags into a variable and then use that variable. This allows you to override them from the command line.

Since the list of default flags is usually sensible, I like to use `+=` so I can add to rather than override my C flags. `CFLAGS=-pedantic make` for example.

I also have `OPTIMIZE` separate so I can normally work with debugging builds, but then make optimized builds for release. `make OPTIMIZE=-O3`. That's a `make` argument rather than an environment variable to tell `make` to override the hard coded assignment in the Makefile.

```
OPTIMIZE = -g
CFLAGS += -std=c99 -Wall $(OPTIMIZE)

operation: operation.o operation_functions.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o operation operation.o operation_functions.o
```